# A breakpoint hit in the OnMeasureItem handler causes Delphi to refuse to switch focus from the debugged application to other applications

Tags: debugging, delphi-6

I make an owner drawn popup menu and set a breakpoint in `OnMeasureItem` handler of its items.

Then I run the debugged application, and when I call the popup menu on the right click, breakpoint triggers, but this triggering doesn't bring Delphi user interface to the front. Moreover, I cannot bring to the front manually neither Delphi not any other application, currently running and newly launched, except the task manager. They are only blinking with taskbar buttons when I try to change focus to them. Alt-Tab doesn't have any effect.

I cannot even kill the debugged application. The only solution is to kill Delphi, then remember which files and on which lines were opened.

Is there some remedy for that? Some command line tool that can order Delphi to end debug session gracefully?